# Handle snort's rules remotely

Tags: snort

I have multiple snort sensors in my network and i would like to handle the rules of each one remotely.

Is there any software that do that ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you can give more details on your network maybe we can recommend something more specific.
But a very general answer would be that you can use one of the rule managers:
PolMan
OinkMaster
or
pulled_pork

however, maybe you are better off using a more general server management tool like apache puppet